# How to add the Github "BigFloat" library to my c++ project

Tags: c++

(Sorry if this question is glaringly obvious or poorly written as I am fairly inexperienced to any form of coding and this website) I've been trying to include a library called "Big float" from github to my project as it needs to calculate very large numbers with high precision but my compiler doesn't recognise the library. I am using codeblocks version 20.03. I have tried: project ->
build options -> linker settings and then adding the files there but to no avail. I also tried: settings -> compiler -> linker settings and adding the files in there.

link:https://github.com/Mariotti94/BigFloat

Again, sorry for my lack of knowledge and thank you.

Comment: You likely want to add `BigFloat.cc` and `Factorial.cpp` to your project and use the `BigFloat.h` header.

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do, you might want to consider [`boost/multiprecision`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library you are referring to appears to consist of source code only. This means you need to compile it yourself. Just add the "BigFloat.cc" and "BigFloat.h" files to your project. Then, in your own code, write `#include "BigFloat.h"` to get access to the `BigFloat` class.